# "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous" error when iterating through a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, append

I am attempting to add to a list "quantities" on the conditions that the column "Todays Price" is above the column "Target Price" in a dataframe entitled active_positions.

I tried the following code:

```
for index, row in active_positions.iterrows():
    if row['Todays Price'] >= row['Target Price']:
        quantities.append(row['Quantity'])
```

When I attempt this, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I've looked up other people who have this issue, and the advice I've seen is to use "&" instead of "and", which does not apply to this situation ( I don't think).

I've also seen the suggestion of using np.where(condition, effect-A, effect-B).  This wouldn't work for me, as I don't want to add anything to the list "quantities" if the conditions are not met, and when I attempted to do:

```
for index, row in active_positions.iterrows():
above_target = row['Todays Price'] >= row['Target Price']
quantities.append(np.where(above_target, row['Quantity'],))

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-656-9c9f6030d250>", line 3, in <module>
    quantities.append(np.where(above_target, row['Quantity'],))

ValueError: either both or neither of x and y should be given
```

I know I could fix this by putting a zero after the "row['Quantity]" expression in the np.where clause, however like I said, I don't want to be adding zeroes to the quantities list.

Please advise, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

In the interests of speed, you should not be attempting to iterate through your dataframe. If you only want values of `Quantity` where your condition is True, you can apply a mask as below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = {'Todays Price': [1, 2, 1, 5, 6], 'Target Price': [1, 3, 2, 4, 3], 
     'Quantity': [10, 11, 12, 13, 15]}

df = pd.DataFrame(a)

quantities = df[df['Todays Price'] >= df['Target Price']]['Quantity']
quantities_list = quantities.values.tolist() # For pure Python list result

# Or perhaps more clearly for the same result:

mask = df['Todays Price'] >= df['Target Price']

quantities = df[mask]['Quantity']
quantities_list = quantities.values.tolist()
```

Comment: This did not fix my error.  I still received the same Valueerror as before.

Comment: @DavidWilliam My code is a self-contained example, which won't throw an error. Either there is something else in your data that you've not given or you've adapted the solution incorrectly to your code base. Please see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) that reproduces your continuing issue.

Comment: @DavidWilliam the only thing that I can think of without that is that you kept the `for index, row in active_positions.iterrows():` loop, which should not exist anymore.